# Using ByteStream for reading UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I was using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to read characters from a text file in UTF-8 and write the data to another (essentially copying the contents).

FileInputStream reads 1 byte serially and FileOutputStream writes one byte serially to a text file.

I first did this for normal input .txt file with content in English. Worked, as it should. Then I modified my input text file and wrote some Japanese characters in it (using google translate). Each character was of 3 bytes.

I did the same process again with the new text file and this also worked perfectly. Since only 1 byte is read at a time, shouldn't the information have been corrupted (Since each japanese character was of 3 bytes). I want to ask why does FileInputStream work with 3 byte characters as well. Here is the code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FileInputStream in=null;
        FileOutputStream out=null;
        try{
            File f=new File("C:/Users/harsh/Desktop/xanadu.txt.txt");
            in=new FileInputStream(f);
            out=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/harsh/Desktop/xanadu333.txt");
            int c;
            while((c=in.read())!=-1){
                out.write(c);
            }
        }
        finally{
            if(in!=null){
                in.close();
            }
            if(out!=null){
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT - consider the text file as 私の名前はアンソニーです (My name is Anthony) a 39 byte file. I am getting the same output, i.e. , 私の名前はアンソニーです in my output text file.
Also, I also wrote `out.write(97) //97 as ascii of a` just after `out.write(c)` and then output file was all broken

Comment: In java there is a strict difference of notions. `byte` is 1 byte, `byte[]` is binary data. `String, char` is Unicode text. `char` is a two-bytes UTF-16 encoded byte. If `byte`s in some encoding are converted to String one need s the encoding the bytes are in. Your code does a pure binary copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a Japanese character to a file, using UTF-8 encoding, you are effectively writing three bytes to it.

The loop you declared doesn't care about characters, it cares about bytes.

```
while((c=in.read())!=-1){
    out.write(c);
    if(c=='r'){
        break;
    }
}
```

and because the input file contains three bytes, it simply loops three times.

**EDIT:** The reason you corrupt everything after doing a `out.write(97)` directly after `out.write(c)` is because the three bytes representing a single Japanese character are no longer contiguous. This breaks the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Yes,that is true, but that's not my doubt. Let us assume I have 1 japanese character in my file. In UTF-8, the size of file would be 6 bytes. When using this code and writing the data to another file. Shouldn't that 1 japanese character be separated into 3 x 1 byte characters(essentially making it corrupted)?

Comment: Also ignore that c equals 'r' part, that was me just experimenting. Also take this as an example.      私の名前はアンソニーです(My name is Anthony).

Comment: @HarshPathak well, it writes the bytes in the same order as it reads them. So the written bytes should still form a valid UTF-8 encoded character.

Comment: If that is the case, then would there be any difference between byte stream and character stream in terms of copying unicode text from one text file to another?

Comment: @HarshPathak I would suggest using a byte stream to avoid caring about a file's encoding.

Comment: Also, according to the code, we are not closing  output stream unless the entire input file has been copied to the new output file. Now if I make changes to my input text file, particularly as 私の名前はアンソニーですabcd  @(43 bytes), so in the background a binary copy takes place. Also output wont be saved in the new file unless we close the output stream. Then after closing, how does the system know that first 12 characters are meant to be 3 bytes each, followed by 4x(1 byte) characters and then again 3 byte character. Why not(for example) display all as packets of just 1 bytes,thus corrupting it.

Comment: @HarshPathak The UTF-8 encoding itself knows how to take care of that.